# Javascript - Slashes are replaced by spaces

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an li element in my html code via javascript. This li will have an onclick function. The problem is that trying to pass a file path as an argument in the loadDoc2() function, some problems occur. I am including the code.

```
    function myFunction(){ 
          var x = "NEW";
          var file = "'/static/BRANDS/PERLA/NEW COL/XML Files/NEW COL.xml'";
          lis = "<li><a onclick='loadXMLDoc2(" + file + ")'>" + x + "</a></li>";
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = lis;
        }
```

This gives me `<a onclick="loadXMLDoc2(" static brands perla new col xml files new col.xml')'>NEW</a>`. The slashes are replaced by spaces and letters are low case. The result that I need is `<a onclick="loadXMLDoc2('/static/BRANDS/PERLA/NEW COL/XML Files/NEW COL.xml')">NEW</a>`
I have tried many things such as .replace("\", "//") but it didn't work.

Comment: why do you have quotes in quotes? Unless i am mistaken this should not be necessary.

Comment: He's playing with html strings, you needs quotes in quotes for them to be printed out on the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you start your onclick with ' and file has a ' at the start, so it closes the onclick attribute. So it looks like

```
<li><a onclick='loadXMLDoc2('/static/BRANDS/PERLA/NEW COL/XML Files/NEW COL.xml')'>NEW</a></li>
```

I suggest you use javascript to bind the event, it's gonna be way easier.

```
function myFunction(){ 
      var x = "NEW";
      var file = "/static/BRANDS/PERLA/NEW COL/XML Files/NEW COL.xml";
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.innerHTML = x;
      a.onclick = function(){
          loadXMLDoc2(file);
      }
      li.appendChild(a);
      document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: Damn ya beat me :D

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<script>
 var container = document.getElementById('container');
 var li = document.createElement('li');
 li.innerText = "Im a list item";
 li.onclick = function(){
  console.log('I was clicked');
 }
 
 container.appendChild(li);
</script>
```

Comment: A code dump won't help much... Please elaborate on what you did, and why... Since you didn't use OP's code there is chances that they won't be able to port it.

Comment: The reason the OP's code doesn't work is I don't think you can dynamically insert elements into the markup that call javascript functions. The best way is to pragmatically create the element, attach an event listener to the onclick even and insert it as a child element into the DOM. However on the contrary, I believe if the OP cannot adapt this example to work within his own code then he doesn't really deserve it and should learn the fundamentals first.

Answer (score 0):

you appear to have conflicting quotes.

`lis === "<li><a onclick='loadXMLDoc2('/static/BRANDS/PERLA/NEW-COL/XML-Files/NEW COL.xml')'>NEW</a></li>"`

note that `k='loadXMLDoc2('/` will open then close the quotes.  fixed by changing single to double quotes:

```
var x = "NEW";
var file = "'/static/BRANDS/PERLA/NEW-COL/XML-Files/NEW COL.xml'";
lis = `<li><a onclick="loadXMLDoc2(${file})">${x}</a></li>`;
document.body.innerHTML = lis;
```